# How to pass object to float ....ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I need help with this code. I've tried to change the column object of my dataframe to float using this code and it shows ... ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2685,040344'. This one is the first value of df1['Puissance']. I have other columns as objects and the program shows the same problem.

I want then create a new column call

```
df1['Torque']=float(df1['Puissance']) // float(df1['Vitesse'])
```

but still shows the problem. I can't change the object to float.

Is this a problem from the pd.read_csv?

How can I resolve the problem?

I've already tried #df1['Puissance'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['Puissance'], errors='ignore', downcast='float') and shows the same problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\FGFGJ\\Documents\\Écorçage 2018\\Volet_1\\past5\\2A_.txt", sep='\t')

df1['Puissance']=df1.Puissance.astype(float, errors='raise')

#df1.dtypes
```

Comment: The error gives a hint: You're using comma `,` as decimal sign, but Python/Pandas needs decimal dot `.` to convert strings to floats. Two possible solutions: (1) Specify decimal sign using the `decimal` argument on data import (see docs for details: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) or (2) replace comma with dot by using `str.replace()` on the desired column(s) which themselves are pandas.Series, so `pandas.Series.str.replace()` can be applied (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options when using `pandas.read_csv`. The simplest, in your case, would probably be to pass `decimal=","` as parameter. That way pandas will recognize your Puissance column as numeric.

**EDIT**

For more information on the possible parameters see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). If you need to convert multiple columns to different dtypes you can use `dtype={<column>: <dtype>}`.